# Error in pkcs11_generate:1355: PKCS #11 user error

Tags: pkcs#11, softhsm

I'm trying to generate a public/private keypair in softHSM, for this I have installed a provider in openssl.

Using these commands I end up in a "user error"

```
+ softhsm2-util --init-token --free --label token-label --so-pin mysopin1 --pin mysecret1
Slot 0 has a free/uninitialized token.
The token has been initialized and is reassigned to slot 251791662

++ p11tool --list-token-urls
++ grep token-label
+ export 'TOKEN=pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;manufacturer=SoftHSM%20project;serial=95c88c090f02092e;token=token-label'
+ TOKEN='pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;manufacturer=SoftHSM%20project;serial=95c88c090f02092e;token=token-label'

+ p11tool --set-so-pin=mysopin1 --initialize 'pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;manufacturer=SoftHSM%20project;serial=95c88c090f02092e;token=token-label' --label token-label
Initializing token... done

Token was successfully initialized; use --initialize-pin and --initialize-so-pin to set or reset PINs

+ p11tool --login --set-so-pin=mysopin1 --generate-privkey=Ed25519 --bits 1024 --set-pin=mysecret1 --outfile MyNewKey.pub 'pkcs11:model=SoftHSM%20v2;manufacturer=SoftHSM%20project;serial=95c88c090f02092e;token=token-label' --label token-label
Generating an EdDSA (Ed25519) key...
Error in pkcs11_generate:1355: PKCS #11 user error
```

I have searched up a number of examples of using p11tool and they all say this is the way to run the commands, and `Generating an EdDSA (Ed25519) key...` indicates that something works.

This also puzzles me, but adding --initialize-pin and `--initialize-so-pin` does not help.

```
Token was successfully initialized; use --initialize-pin and --initialize-so-pin to set or reset PINs
```

This is how I install the tools with a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
USER root
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y opensc git build-essential automake libtool libengine-pkcs11-openssl libp11-kit-dev libp11-dev gnutls-bin libcppunit-dev libssl-dev softhsm
COPY openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN openssl engine pkcs11 -t
```

The full example with a Dockerfile can be seen here: https://gitlab.com/kjeld.flarup/softhsmdemo

Answer (score 1):

The error goes away if I run this first:

```
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so --login --login-type so --so-pin mysecret1 --init-pin --new-pin mysecret1
```